# Does Hue support Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: hue, google-cloud-bigtable

I want to know whether Hue supports Bigtable.

It mostly depends on does Hue use coprocessor feature in HBase. Also Hue should run outside of Hadoop cluster. It means there is no access to ZooKeeper.

Answer (score 1):

Hue doesn't support BigTable.

After some search I discovered a quora post about Hbase viewers and
spot h-rider on github.
It's open source project.

It looks like abandoned, though after I spent 3 hours I was able to connect to BigTable (see tables and rows)

Comment: If Google BigTable uses HBase Thrift V1 API, Hue can connect to it with its HBase Browser app http://gethue.com/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser/

Comment: Google Bigtable does support thrift: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/python/thrift

I'm not sure if it's v1.