# Connect BigTable with Apache Hue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, hue, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I have been using Google Bigtable from GCP, but need suggestions in connecting it to a GUI client like Apache Hue. The documentation on BigTable doesn't have much information on visualization. I have been using the cbt tool till now, but it doesn't provide GUI.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.gethue.com/administrator/configuration/connectors/#google-bigquery ?

Comment: That documentation is for bigquery, my concern is about the bigtable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post which discuss the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35655768/9330208). I suggest you to give it a look.

Additionally I don't suggest you to use Apache HUE with GCP Big Table as this procedure is not well documented.

What are you trying to do exactly? If you want to monitor Big Table I suggest you to use the [Cloud Bigtable Monitoring UI](https://medium.com/@duhroach/using-cloud-bigtable-monitoring-ui-40d3f4c726d6)

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldnt find a GUI client for Google Bigtable,
I decided to build one as a VSCode extension.

You can try this out https://github.com/a7ul/vscode-bigtable

It supports querying bigtable and is basically a VSCode extension wrapper over the official nodejs bigtable client